# Solving a PDE boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, problem-solving, boundary-value-problem, linear-pde

Given the 1st order linear PDE
$$\begin{align} 
u_t+u_x &=x, & &x>0,\ t>0  \tag 1 \\
u(x,0) &= \sin x, & &x\geq 0  \tag 2\\
u(0,t)&=t, & &t\geq0          \tag 3
\end{align}$$

And we want to find if the solution is classical or weak.

***Solution***

The method of characteristics gives
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{x}$$

---

***Edited***

Νow from the first equality it follows that
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1} \implies x=t+c_1 \implies c_1=x-t$$
and from the second
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{x}=\frac{du}{t+c_1} \implies u=c_2+\frac{(t+c_1)^2}{2} \implies c_2=u-\frac{x^2}{2}  $$

The general solution of the PDE expressed in the form of implicit equation
$$c_2=G(c_1)$$
So $$u- \frac{x^2}{2}=G(x-t) \implies u=G(x-t)+\frac{x^2}{2} \tag4$$

We want to determine $G$ so conditions $(2)$ and $(3)$ are satisfied.

Now, applying the initial values, we get
\begin{align}
u(x,0) &= \sin x-\frac{x^2}{2} = G(x), & &x \geq 0 \\
u(0,t) &= t = G(-t), & &t \geq 0
\end{align}

It is sufficient then to say that a solution $u(x,t)$ of the given Boundary Value Problem, is the function defined as such :

$$u(x,t) = G(x-t)+\frac{x^2}{2}  \quad \text{where} \quad \begin{cases} G(x) =sinx-\frac{x^2}{2}, \ x>t>0  \\ G(-t) = t ,\ 0<x<t \end{cases}$$

Letting $x := x-t$ and $t := t-x$ in the case of the boundary values. Then :

$$G(x-t) = sinx-\frac{x^2}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad G(x-t) = t-x\quad$$

For $x<t \implies x-t<0$,so  $(4)$ gives
$$u(x,t)=\frac{x^2}{2}+(t-x),\ 0<x<t$$

For $x>t \implies x-t>0$, so $(4)$ gives

$$u(x,t)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{(x-t)^2}{2}+sin(x-t) ,\ x>t>0 $$

Therefore the solution of the system, if we do the identity at the second branch, is
$$u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{2}+(t-x) ,\quad  0<x<t \quad \\
 xt-\frac{t^2}{2}+sin(x-t),\quad x>t>0 \quad 
\end{cases}$$

Now we have to check if the solution is classical or weak.

$$ \lim_{x\to\ t^{-}} u= \lim_{x\to\ t^{+}} u= \frac{t^2}{2}$$

Thus $u$ is a continuous function $\forall x>0,\ t>0$.

Comment: You solved the second ODE incorrectly as $x = x(t)$ is dependent on $t$ so $$\int x dt \ne xt$$ You have $$\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{du}{x} = \frac{du}{t + c_{1}} \implies \frac{(t + c_{1})^{2}}{2} = u - c_{2} \implies u - \frac{x^{2}}{2} = c_{2}$$

Comment: @MatthewCassell so I have to replace the one I found for x. I was following those steps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3040289/boundary-and-initial-conditions-in-quasi-linear-first-order-pde

Comment: @MathewCassel I solved $u(t)=\int x dt =xt$. Why is that wrong?

Comment: @MatthewCassell Oh, I got it. I have burned my brain cells